# What's the use of the metadata in vs2012 native unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

what's the use of defining metadata in vs2012 native unit tests? They can be defined in sections that start with

```
BEGIN_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE(<methodname>)
    TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE("attribute1", "value1")
END_TEST_METHOD_ATTRIBUTE()
```

and there are even pre-defined macros like "TEST_OWNER" and such - but I can't find a place where they are actually used / displayed. Just for putting them into the source-code, proper documentation would have been sufficient, so I actually wonder where they are used. Can anybody help?

Thank you
Tobias

Answer (score 1):

I think this article on MSDN will answer your question:

[How to manage unit tests in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 : Part 1–Using Traits in the Unit Test Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/09/how-to-manage-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-1-part-1-using-traits-in-the-unit-test-explorer.aspx?Redirected=true)

It explains how VS2012 Update 1 enhanced the Test Explorer to allow filtering of tests based on these test attributes.

> Visual Studio 2012 has a great new Test Explorer.  The Test Explorer is where you see the results of your unit tests.  In Update 1 it has been extended, and you can now organize and filter the test runs based on several conditions, among them your Projects, and Traits.   Traits is a new concept,  a common denominator for several underlying terms, Test Category, Test Property, Priority, and Owner.
>
> Traits are not only useful as a grouping mechanism in the Test Explorer, it also part of what can control which tests you run.  This has been a big request – because it means the developer can focus on the tests relevant to the work, and not be bothered with running other, perhaps long-running tests, which would otherwise slow down the whole development  experience.  No longer with Update 1!

It is written from a C# perspective but I've used the same technique for C++ and C# tests just now. Seems to work well.